# Calculating the Nullity of a Linear Transformation of Polynomials

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $T: V \to \mathbb{R}$, where $V$ is the set of real polynomials of degree $2$ or less. Define $T(p)$ = $ \int_{-1}^{1} p(x)dx$. Show that $T$ is linear, and calculate the dimension of its kernel.

I've got that it's linear, just showing that $T(av_1 + bv_2) = aT(v_1) + bT(v_2)$ with two arbitrary quadratic polynomials.

The kernel, I've calculated as $ \{ ax^2 + bx + c \mid 2a+3b = 0 \}$, with some basic integration and setting it to $0$.

Is its kernel the same dimension? The dimension of $V$ is $3$ because it's 3 basis vectors are $ \{ 1, x, x^2 \}$. Because the kernel consists of only quadratics, and $a$ is not always 0, are the three basis vectors not the same, and thus the nullity of $T$ is 3 as well? Just would like to verify. Thanks.

Comment: You should show your work for the null space (I don’t think your condition $2a+3b=0$ is correct).

Comment: @Clayton I just redid it and found a mistake. Should it be $a + 3c = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you got the kernel wrong as we get
$$\int_{-1}^1 \! ax^2 + bx + c \, \mathrm d x = \frac{2a}{3} + c$$
so for $T(p) = 0$ we need $2a + 3c = 0$ (probably a typo?).

Hence we have one equation restricting our choice of values for three variables, i.e. the kernel has dimension 2 (note that you can freely choose $b$ and either $a$ or $c$ according to the equation above -- the fact that $b$ can be choosen arbitrarily either way stems from the fact that $bx$ is the *odd* part of the polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$ and the integrals of odd functions over intervals symmetric around zero vanish.)

There is another, in my opinion easier, way to get this:
The rank-nullity theorem states that for a linear map $f \colon V \to W$ we have $\dim V = \operatorname{rank} f + \operatorname{nullity} f$.
Applying this to your problem we have $\dim V = 3$ but $\operatorname{rank} T = 1$ as the rank of $T$ is bounded by the dimension of its range (i.e. 1 as $\dim \mathbb R = 1$ as our base field is $\mathbb R$ also) and clearly the rank cannot be 0 as not all such polynomials are mapped to $0$ (take e.g. $x^2$).
Hence we quickly determined $\operatorname{rank} T = 1$ and thus find that $T$ has nullity $2$.

Comment: This helps a lot. I knew I was missing something. The book even mentions that we don't need to compute the actual kernel of the transformation, but I didn't see exactly how that would apply. Thanks for the solution.